Building a fresh .NET 9.0 MAUI project fails with 13 errors
As the title says, building the project fails, showing 13 build errors. I just updated Visual Studio 2022 recently and ticked all the options needed. Creating a fresh project and building  it immediately crashes.
For further information, I'm running it on Windows Machine, which crashes at net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0.
It gives the following errors
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.WinUI.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,40,4,53): error CS0118: 'global::WinRT' is a namespace but is used like a type
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.WinUI.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,57,4,80): error CS0103: The name 'RandomiserVtableClasses' does not exist in the current context
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.WinUI.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,2,4,122): error CS1729: 'WinRTExposedTypeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,40,4,53): error CS0118: 'global::WinRT' is a namespace but is used like a type
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,57,4,80): error CS0103: The name 'RandomiserVtableClasses' does not exist in the current context
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.App.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,2,4,121): error CS1729: 'WinRTExposedTypeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.MainPage.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,40,4,53): error CS0118: 'global::WinRT' is a namespace but is used like a type
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.MainPage.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,57,4,80): error CS0103: The name 'RandomiserVtableClasses' does not exist in the current context
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.MainPage.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,2,4,121): error CS1729: 'WinRTExposedTypeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.AppShell.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,40,4,53): error CS0118: 'global::WinRT' is a namespace but is used like a type
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.AppShell.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,57,4,80): error CS0103: The name 'RandomiserVtableClasses' does not exist in the current context
1>C:\Users\115al\Documents\GitHub\5e-Monster-Randomiser-.NET-Maui-App\5e Randomiser\obj\Debug\net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\WinRT.SourceGenerator\Generator.WinRTAotSourceGenerator\_5e_Randomiser.AppShell.WinRTVtable.g.cs(4,2,4,121): error CS1729: 'WinRTExposedTypeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments
1>Done building project "5e Randomiser.csproj" -- FAILED.

I've attempted the following fixes:
dotnet clean
dotnet build

dotnet workload install maui-windows

Re-Creating a new project

dotnet restore
dotnet build

Installing .NET 9.0 through - [link][1]


  [1]: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-9.0.101-windows-x64-installer


I don't really know what else I could do to try fix it as not even AI could help me.

not even AI could help me: If AI couldn't help, then what chance of helping do us mere humans have?

https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/1809
